# Is there a way to stop the GUI from freezing when calling an external program via command line in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qprocess

I have been trying to create a GUI for a project. I have an 'exe' file that I need to run in the background of the application with the push of a button. I created a threading based function calling for the exe file using qprocess and it works. But the thing is, it freezes the GUI and always shows not responding when trying multiple files...

Is there any way I can reroute the Qprocess so that it does not block the GUI in a way that I can still somehow access the Qprocess exe file output?

Edit#1: The exe file's process is proportional to the amount of "ligand files" the user provides. For testing I have to provide atleast 100 or so files. This causes enough freeze on the GUI that it just says not responsive on the taskbar.

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def testMain(self):
        ligands = glob.glob("*.sdf")
        liglen = len(ligands)
        self.files_2.setText("<b>1/{} Ligand(s)</b>".format(liglen))
        x = self.progressBar.setMaximum(liglen)
        t = threading.Thread(target = self.ligconv(ligands))
        t.start()
    def ligconv (self, ligands):
        process = QProcess()
        cd = "babel.exe"
        for i in ligands:
            tem = re.sub('\..*', '.pdbqt', i)
            ligename = tem
            ar = [receptorname, "-xnrcp", "-O", ligname]
            process.execute(cd, ar)
```

*Post-script*:

- I know that the exe file via cmd route is given the control as soon as I press the button.
- I also know the fact that using Qprocess waitFor commands block the GUI and thus I have already removed them from the code.
- Sorry I can't really show the code that I am using since it is an important project, this is the minimal code for the same :)

Comment: If you don't show us any code, we won't be able to help you: there could be dozens of reasons for this behavior, and we cannot guess. Create a new script based on your current logic so that you can provide us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and edit your question with that.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing `t = threading.Thread(target = self.ligconv(ligands))` in the main thread since your code is equivalent to:

```
res = self.ligconv(ligands)
t = threading.Thread(target = res)
```

Instead target must receive a callable, and if you want to pass extra arguments then you should use args:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=self.ligconv, args=(ligands,))
```

Comment: That just closes the GUI and tries to execute the exe file in the background. Thanks for the help though..